# PHP Session Does Not Work on Website

Tags: php, session, xampp

I made a php session and it worked on my localhost server with XAMPP but when I put it on my site it did not work. I made a simpler one to see if it would work and it still did not.

login_validation.php

```
<?php 
session_start();

$user = $_POST['user'];

if ($user == (--database match--)) { #<== Just to skip all the mysql database stuff that already works.

    $_SESSION['username'] = $user;

    if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
        echo "Logged in, " . $_SESSION['username'] . "<a href='test.php'>Return</a>";
    }
}

?>
```

This page worked on both my site and localhost. On the site, it printed the username given, showing that the session was saved. So I made a blank page called `test.php` to see if it would print the session if it was actually set.

`test.php`

```
<?php
session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    echo $_SESSION['username'];
}
else {
    echo "Not working.";
}
?>
```

It printed out the value of the session on my localhost but not on my site. It gave me "Not Working" as I have set for the else statement above.

I was thinking it was a problem in my phpinfo.php so I analysed each part of the session section with my localhost phpinfo.php file and some of them were the same. others were not.

Session(website) Values: (1st -> Local Value) (2nd-> Master Value)

```
Session Support enabled
Registered save handlers    files user sqlite
Registered serializer handlers  php php_binary wddx

Directive   Local Value Master Value
session.auto_start                  Off Off
session.bug_compat_42               Off Off
session.bug_compat_warn             Off Off
session.cache_expire                180 180
session.cache_limiter               nocache nocache
session.cookie_domain               no value    no value
session.cookie_httponly             Off Off
session.cookie_lifetime             0   0
session.cookie_path                /    /
session.cookie_secure              Off  Off
session.entropy_file               /dev/urandom /dev/urandom
session.entropy_length             0    0
session.gc_divisor                 1000 1000
session.gc_maxlifetime             1440 1440
session.gc_probability              1   1
session.hash_bits_per_character     4   4
session.hash_function               0   0
session.name                        PHPSESSID   PHPSESSID
session.referer_check               no value    no value
session.save_handler                files   files
session.save_path                   /var/php_sessions   /var/php_sessions
session.serialize_handler           php php
session.use_cookies                 On  On
session.use_only_cookies            On  On
session.use_trans_sid               1   1
```

Session(localhost) Values: (1st -> Local Value) (2nd-> Master Value)

```
session.auto_start                      Off Off
session.cache_expire                    180 180
session.cache_limiter                   nocache nocache
session.cookie_domain                   no value    no value
session.cookie_httponly                 Off Off
session.cookie_lifetime                 0   0
session.cookie_path                     /   /
session.cookie_secure                   Off Off
session.entropy_file                    no value    no value
session.entropy_length                  0   0
session.gc_divisor                      1000    1000
session.gc_maxlifetime                  1440    1440
session.gc_probability                  1       1
session.hash_bits_per_character         5       5
session.hash_function                   0       0
session.name                            PHPSESSID   PHPSESSID
session.referer_check                   no value    no value
session.save_handler                    files   files
session.save_path                       C:\xampp\tmp    C:\xampp\tmp
session.serialize_handler               php     php
session.upload_progress.cleanup         On      On
session.upload_progress.enabled         On      On
session.upload_progress.freq            1%      1%
session.upload_progress.min_freq        1       1
session.upload_progress.name            PHP_SESSION_UPLOAD_PROGRESS  PHP_SESSION_UPLOAD_PROGRESS
session.upload_progress.prefix          upload_progress_    upload_progress_
session.use_cookies                     On      On
session.use_only_cookies                Off     Off
session.use_strict_mode                 Off     Off
session.use_trans_sid                   0       0
```

I'm not sure if the information of phpinfo() is vital or not but I hope it may solve the issue.

Comment: ALso I checked the session.save_path and found the files for my xampp sessions saved in C:\xampp\tmp, but in my website session.save_path, the file /var/php_sessions does not exist. Do I have to make the file or is it just not usually visible to me?

Comment: login_validation.php and test.php are in the same server domain?

Comment: You might need to create the  directory `/var/php_sessions` and give it write permissions.

Comment: right after start_session(), if you do a print_r($_SESSION) does it print anything (should be a session ID)? If not, I suspect it's a permissions issue. Where is your site hosted? Like Jeemusu stated, your host might have changed the session save path to something different than the default.

Comment: On the login_val.php file, I put 
 print_r($_SESSION); after i checked if it is set and it printed out Array ( [username] => value ) but when I click return and it takes me to test.php it gives me Array ( ). I am using domain.com site hosting. I'll contact customer service to see about the path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set your php.ini `session.save_path` value to `/tmp`, like this

```
session.save_path = "/tmp"
```

If you don't have access to overwrite php.ini file on the server, you may try to set the path using

```
session_save_path("/tmp");
```

Use the above sentence before calling `session_start();`

Comment: Thank you. It worked after I changed the path in php.ini to /tmp and created a /tmp directory.